# Webpack shows syntaxt error while running the command

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi everyone I am trying to follow a video of react js I am developing a app seeing that tutorial. Got stuck with syntax error and not able to find any solutions for it.Below is my code:
app.js:

```
var React = require('react');

var APP = React.createClass({
    render(){
       return (<h1>Hello World from React</h1>);
    }
});

module.exports = APP;
```

app-server.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(express.static('./node_modules/bootstrap/dist'));

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Polling server is running at 'http://localhost:3000'");
```

app-client.js

```
var React = require('react');
var APP = require('./components/app');

React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./app-client.js",
output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            exclude: /(node_modules|app-server.js)/,
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {                 
                presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

};

Error in command line:

```
$ webpack
Hash: efea76b1048c3a97b963
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 2344ms
+ 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./app-client.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Sanjay/Documents/node_project/start/app-client.js: Unexpected token (4:13)

2 | var APP = require('./components/app');
3 |
> 4 | React.render(<APP />, document.getElementById('react-container'));
|              ^
```

Any help would be appreciated to clear my doubt.

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `react-dom` rather than `react` in app-client.js?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error on different OS (Linux) using latest webpack (1.13.2) and ReactDOM.render().  This project already works in another directory using previously installed node modules, so I currently suspect this is an emergent bug in one of my dev-dependencies.